# How to deleted multiple rows from backgrid js

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, marionette, backgrid

i am have integrated [backgrid.js](http://backgridjs.com) with backbone.marionnette.js. there is spec in the document as how to delete a single row or column from grid as follows

```
// Remove a column
var genderCol = grid.columns.where({ name: "gender" });
grid.removeColumn(genderCol);

// Remove rows
var musketeers = grid.collection.where({ job: "Musketeer" });
grid.removeRow(musketeers);
```

but how to `remove multiple rows from the grid as well as in the database using backgrid.js`

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

Call Backbone.Model#destroy() to remove and destroy a model from a collection. Backbone has no batch removal facility so you will have to remove them one by one.

Comment: Please see my answer and +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

it is as simple as `collection.add or collection.remove`

Refer for removing same is applicable for add.[this](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove)

to get a collection of selected models from [backgrid](http://backgridjs.com/)

```
var selectedModels = grid.getSelectedModels();
```

to remove

```
backgriCollections.remove(selectedModels);
```

Very simple.

Comment: Just removing them won't destroy them on the server. You have to call destroy on every single one of the models to delete them on the server.

Comment: understood, You point is considered when it is removed from collection :)